# Is there any way to control current precisely with Arduino without using a DC-DC converter?

Tags: arduino-uno, current

I have a circuit that consists of a torquer. Its torque is directly proportional to the current in the circuit. I want to precisely control the torque provided by the torquer and hence need to control the current in the circuit. Which is the best technique you would prefer using Arduino?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "control current", what current and what voltage.

Comment: @Milliways I have a constant voltage source and wish to control the current in the circuit with Arduino. Can it be done using PWM?

Comment: If you want any sensible answer you need the provide detail of what you are trying to control.

Comment: @Milliways I have edited the question. I hope it has enough detail :)

Comment: There isn't much detail, like part numbers. You may as well ask if the Arduino can be used on the International Space Station. No doubt it could, but you need to provide more detail as to what it is expected to do, and in conjunction with what other circuitry.

Comment: Add a current sense resistor. Connect that to an analog pin so you can measure the current. Then change the PWM output value till the current is what you want it to be. Some people use a PID control loop for this.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino (like other microcontrollers) is a digital device. It doesn't "control current" on its own. It has outputs which can either be off or on. Off is 0V and on is 5V (assuming you are powering it from a 5V supply). The continuous current you can drawn from output pins is 20 mA.

You can use PWM to effectively reduce the power output (for example, a 50% duty cycle would be half on and half off, thus you would have 50% power).

If you drive your torquer from some sort of transistor (eg. a MOSFET) then PWM could conceivably achieve what you are wanting to do. A link to this device would be helpful. Plus, the other circuitry you have in mind.

Comment: Yes I have planned to include MOSFET switches. Could you provide details on how to do so? I am a beginner....

Comment: @yobro97. Google "using MOSFET as a switch".